# How can I convert the value I get with date range picker to two seperate date and time?

Tags: javascript, parsing, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I need to get the start date, start time, end date and end time values ​​separately that I got with the daterangepicker.

```
startinnerDate = document.getElementById('reservationtime').value;
```

Incoming value: "07/14/2021 12:00 AM - 08/10/2021 11:00 PM"

how can i separate it?

Comment: [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the optimal one and not flexible, but very clear for understanding

```js
const startinnerDate = "07/14/2021 12:00 AM - 08/10/2021 11:00 PM"
const [start, end]  = startinnerDate.split(' - ');
const [startDate, startTime, startTimePeriod] = start.split(' ');
const [endDate, endTime, endTimePeriod] = end.split(' ');
console.log('date >>> ', startDate, '| time >>> ', startTime + ' ' + startTimePeriod);
console.log('date >>> ', endDate, '| time >>> ', endTime + ' ' + endTimePeriod);
```

Comment: it worked. thanks. I also need to find the day value. For example if startdate= "14/07/2021" how can I get the value of Wednesday as 3?

Comment: The best one would be to convert dates+time string into the Date objects. After you anything you need - day, month, year, hours, minutes. Just read the docs how to do that. Don't think that should explain right here.
 
Not optimal. startDate and endDate are from prev code snippet
```
const startDayOfWeek = new Date(startDate).getDay();
const endDayOfWeek = new Date(endDate).getDay();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve with a couple of split:

```js
const res = "07/14/2021 12:00 AM - 08/10/2021 11:00 PM";

function parseRes(res) {
  const [d1, d2] = res.split("-");
  const [departureDate, departureTime] = d1.trim().split(/\d\s\d/);
  const [arrivalDate, arrivalTime] = d2.trim().split(/\d\s\d/);
  return {departureDate, departureTime, arrivalDate, arrivalTime};
}

console.log(parseRes(res));
```